# Need help writing a .cmd file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am learning to customize a windows deployment image using Microsoft Deployment Toolkit's Workbench Task Sequence. I am adding an msi package using a .cmd file I created to perform a silent "Client" installation. But even though the following works at the CMD line, it won't work in a cmd file:

```
@echo off

c:\msiexec /i install.msi /l*vx C:\Slave_2_Install_ETIMS_log.txt INSTALL_SLAVE=true /quiet
```

I need to have this cmd file perform the silent install when referenced in the task sequence line in Workbench:

```
cmd /c %Deployroot%\Applications\ETIMS\Install.cmd
```

But I will figure out how the syntax applies in the above statement once I get the answer to why my .cmd file doesn't work but the same line works at the command prompt.

Comment: What doesn't work?  One issue is the location of `install.msi`.  Unless the "current directory" is set to the directory that contains `install.msi`, that's not going to work.

Comment: are you sure that the very same line works in the command line? is it `c:\msiexec` what you type or just `msiexec` ??

Comment: it must be something about the location of the required files msiexec install.msi etc

Comment: If "install,msi" is supposed to be in the same directory as the batch file, you can use the awful construct `"%~dp0install.msi"`.  "%0" always returns the path of the script being run, and the "~dp" modifier returns only the directory part.

Comment: It seems unlikely that the `msiexec` executable is in the root directory. It is likely should be referenced as "%SystemRoot%\System32\msiexec.exe". And, frankly, this should already be in the PATH such that only using `msiexec` would work. From a `cmd` prompt, what is the output of `where msiexec`?

Comment: PA, Yes, I did put the C:\ in the .cmd file by mistake so I took it out but still the file does nothing even if I run it as administrator. The install.msi and the install.cmd are both in the same directory, i.e. on the C:\ drive. The command works perfectly from C:\ at the command prompt, I just don't know how to put that into a .cmd file and have it work.

Comment: where mdiexec is at "C:\Windows\System32\msiexec".

Comment: I still need to know how to get "msiexec /i install.msi /l*vx C:\Slave_2_Install_ETIMS_log.txt INSTALL_SLAVE=true /quiet" to work in a .cmd file or .bat file. Both the install.msi and the install.cmd that I'm trying to ues to install it are on C:\. running the string at the command prompt works perfectly but I don't have a clue how to write a file that will execute it when I put the file in an image. Any help will be greatly apprietiated.

Comment: Have you tried to change to the folder where the .cmd and .msi files are before running the installer?  Like this: `cmd /c (cd "%Deployroot%\Applications\ETIMS"&Install.cmd)`

Comment: I just want to say thank you to Jim Roberts, PA, and lit for your input. Not just trying to be a nice guy - you all included information about directories, paths, and ~dp that was missing in my brain. I really ought to take a formal class on scripting but for now, I get a lot from gleening other peoples answers to my nubie questions. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the command I needed to do what I wanted to do.
One of my mistakes was that I began my file with @echo off - apparently not needed in a .cmd file.
solution I was looking for:

msiexec.exe /quiet /i %~DP0ETIMS_Client.msi INSTALL_SLAVE="TRUE"

Thank you all for the responses.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Roberts, your answers are very informative.